# Order of TForm creation and destruction and threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, user-interface, c++builder

I have a thread which calls functions of certain form to update this form. When task is done, thread updates form with results, using `Synchronize` and it all works fine while the program is running.

The problem happens when the thread is running and I close the program I got access violation. It was caused by thread updating form which was already released. After rearranging order of form creation (calls to `Application->CreateForm`) it worked fine because now the form that holds thread code is created before form that is updated. It seems that order of destruction is reverse to creation order.

I also added some code in form destructor to make sure thread is terminated if form is destroyed before form with the thread code. So rearranging form creation order and/or code in form destructor solves the problem.

But I have 3 questions:

1. What is the order in which created forms are destroyed? Is it reverse of the creation order as I assume now?
2. Is there a better way to do the above task - update form GUI items after thread is done processing data. Right now I do it from thread itself using `Synchronize` but someone experienced with threads may have better idea. One other idea I had was to even remove a bunch of `CreateForm` generated by compiler and create them manually, only create main form using `CreateForm` to better control order of destruction (as suggested by Rob Kennedy - http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/createform).
3. How expensive is dynamic form creation/destruction in typical application? Is it better to use form Hide and keep in memory or destroy it on close?

Comment: 1) Yes, destroyed in reverse order 2) the wheel reinvented. Its better to rearrange the logic 3) depends on what you've designed on them, may be very heavy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a component with an `Owner`, the `Owner` adds your component to its list of components that it owns. That happens in this code:

```
procedure TComponent.Insert(AComponent: TComponent);
begin
  if FComponents = nil then FComponents := TList<TComponent>.Create;
  FComponents.Add(AComponent);
  if FSortedComponents <> nil then
    AddSortedComponent(AComponent);
  AComponent.FOwner := Self;
end;
```

As you can see the component is added to the end of the list.

When the owner is destroyed, it calls `DestroyComponents`:

```
procedure TComponent.DestroyComponents;
var
  Instance: TComponent;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FSortedComponents);
  while FComponents <> nil do
  begin
    Instance := FComponents.Last;
    if (csFreeNotification in Instance.FComponentState)
      or (FComponentState * [csDesigning, csInline] = [csDesigning, csInline]) then
      RemoveComponent(Instance)
    else
      Remove(Instance);
    Instance.Destroy;
  end;
end;
```

As you can see, the loop processes the last member first. So, components are destroyed in reverse order.

Personally I would not rely on destruction order. If the form needs to be sure that the thread is terminated before the form is destroyed, I would write code in the form's destructor to enforce that.

Using `Synchronize` is a perfectly respectable solution to many problems. Whether or not it's the best solution to your problem is impossible me to say because you have not fully described your problem.

> How expensive is dynamic form creation/destruction in typical application?

Not very. Typically forms are shown in response to user interaction. Programs can create forms a lot faster than users can process them. So dynamically creating forms is seldom a problem. If you wanted to create and destroy thousands of forms a second that might be a problem. But that would be bizarre.